# Are people better at interpreting CNF or DNF?

Tags: mathematical-psychology, mathematical-ability

We have a development in our application in which our users can create a report based on different parameters, say ($x_1,\dots,x_n$), with each $x_i$ taking values in a set $X_i$.

The report can take as input any type of logical formula of the form $x_{k_1} @ \dots @ x_{k_m}$ where $@$ represents a disjuntion $\lor$ or a conjuction $\land$ ($@ \in \{\land, \lor\}$). The report will return a population whose features under the formula are true. For example, I can input the formula $$(x_{k_1} < 50 ) \land (x_{k_2} = T \lor x_{k_3} =F)$$ and I will see all the results with those parameters satisfied.

A known result in Boolean logic says that any type of such formula can be represented in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF) or [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (DNF).

Do you know of any research on the question of whether humans are better at interpreting logical formulas in CNF or DNF versus a less structured form? Moreover, is there any research on whether CNF or DNF is more intuitive than the other?